# I want to click on a radio button

Tags: javascript

i am trying to click on Home Radio button, I try many methods that you can see inline // but i didn't get that. please tell me where I am doing mistakes.

```
  if (key==="bill-address") {
                    console.log("bill-address")
    
                    //setvalue(Data[key].formname, Data[key].value)
                    //$("[title='"+Data["dba"].formname+"']")[0].click()
                    $("[title='"+Data["bill-address"].formname+"']")[0].click()
                    //$("[title='"+Data[""].formname+"']")[0].click()
                    await wait(2000)
                }
```

[i am trying to click on Home. please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAskZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("[title='"+Data["bill-address"].formname+"']")[0].checked = true;
```

Comment: by using this it gives error that checked is not a function

Comment: jquery way is:
`$("[title='"+Data["bill-address"].formname+"']")[0].prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...)[0].prop is not a function

Comment: try without [0] `$("[title='"+Data["bill-address"].formname+"']").prop('checked', true)`

Answer (score -1):

Native JS solution:

```
 document.getElementById("_1234").checked = true;
```

JQuery solution:

```
 $("#_1234").prop("checked", true);
```

So in your case:

```
 $("[title|='"+Data["bill-address"].formname+"']")[0].prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: by using this it gives error that prop is not a funtions

Comment: @AbdulHaqAsif I have edited my answer. You need to put a | after the attribute in the selector, e.g. $("[attribute|='value']")

Comment: still have error prop is not a function and code not executed this line

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...)[0].prop is not a function

Comment: By appending `[0]` after your jQuery selector you retrieve the native DOM element, which doesn not have `prop` or any other jQuery API.